# EXCEL VBA word to pdf multiple times SaveAs2

Tags: vba, excel, pdf, ms-word

I whould like to fill a word with values and export to pdf multiple times.

If is use a SaveAs2 the firt time it make a pdf but second or third it doesen't  work.

```
'ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:="C:\alap\" & fajlneve & ".pdf", FileFormat:=wdFormatPDF
```

If I use the CutePDf printer, the result is the same, first time i=1 it works, but second it doesen't.

```
Public compname As String
Public filename As String


Function FillwordForm()

Dim appword As Word.Application
Dim doc As Word.Document
Dim Path As String


On Error Resume Next
Error.Clear


Set appword = GetObject(, "word.application")
If Err.Number <> 0 Then

Set appword = New Word.Application
appword.Visible = True

End If
Path = "C:\pelda\MINTA.docx"
Set doc = appword.Documents.Open(Path, , True)

With doc

    .formfields("szerzCegnev").result = compname

End With

appword.Visible = True
appword.Activate

Set doc = Nothing
Set appword = Nothing

appword.ActivePrinter = "CutePDF Writer"

ActiveDocument.PrintOut OutPutFileName:="C:\pelda\" & filename & ".pdf"

ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges

Word.Application.Quit

End Function


  '---------------------------------------------------------------


Sub cucc()

For i = 1 To 2

compname = Cells(i, 1)
filename = Cells(i, 2)
Call FillwordForm

Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: There is no i variable. You're probably just overwriting the same file every time..

Comment: Please describe exactly HOW it "doesn't work".

Answer (score 1):

can you use:

```
    ActiveDocument.SaveAs2(docname,17);
```

?
(17 is PDF-format -[link to fileformats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdsaveformat?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=word-pia))

Greetz